# pgadmin crash when click SQL query button

Tags: crash, pgadmin

I installed pgAdmin 3 on my windows 64bit system, when I connect to some server, click on the SQL button to execute some script, it crashed, i checked the error log, it says

> 2012-08-05 08:10:00 ERROR  : ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "adminpack"
>   HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.

Can you help me to solve this problem? thanks!

Comment: Please provide the version numbers of pgAdmin and PostgreSQL in use.

Comment: pgAdmin version 1.14.3(Jun 1 2012)

Comment: pgAdmin version 1.14.3(Jun 1 2012), PostgreSQL version 9.1.3

Answer (score 2):

[`adminpack`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/adminpack.html) is an optional extension. pgAdmin should definitely not crash if you don't have it installed.

You can try to install it manually. In PostgreSQL 9.1 run once in one of your databases:

```
CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;
```

You must be superuser for that. Normally the database user `postgres` is superuser.