# PgAdmin sometimes crash when clicking SQL query button

Tags: postgresql, crash, pgadmin

I know this question may be seen as a duplicate with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11838493/1801588). I even have almost the same configuration (PostgreSQL 9.1.3, pgAdmin III 1.14.3, 32 bit Windows). What is the difference and the reason I ask a new question is that my PgAdmin doesn't crash always (just mostly) and that the cause of the problem is different - in linked question the problem was with missing adminpack, but I have adminpack installed and it works well, so the answer for linked question doesn't work for me.

Do you have any ideas where the problem could be?

EDIT: PgAdmin doesn't crash at other occasions (well, unless I do someting that obviously deserves a crash), just while trying to open SQL query window. It's worse and worse as time goes on, now it's almost "always". The problem is not "connection specific" - frequence of crashing is the same for different server connections.

EDIT2: I reinstalled PgAdmin and nothing have changed. I'm starting to suspect PostgreSQL 9.1.3 or even PostGIS 2.0.1 of the problem.

Comment: I get a lot of crashes (actually the app just *vanishes*) when the server it's connected to gets reset or goes offline or something.  pgAdmin doesn't seem to handle that scenario very well.

Comment: I get a lot of crashes in pgadmin3. A few per day. Most indeed seem to be related to opening/closing connections, lost connections and such. I use pgadmin *only* for browsing the databases. Editing is best done in an editor. (vi(m) has never failed me) I don't know about the versions; it has always been this way. But, hey, it's C++ !)

Comment: could you install postgresql locally on the machine to 100% rule out potential packet loss issues? or, is the database server on the machine already?

Comment: @JoshuaBurns: I have one connection to a server online and others on the machine. As far as I remember this problem occured while offline too, but I'll try it again. Definitely it first occured when working on one of the databases on the machine.

Comment: are you running windows xp, vista, or 7? also, is it the 32-bit version of windows or 64-bit?

Comment: @JoshuaBurns: 32-bit Windows XP

Comment: man it's hard to say. here's an article which may be related, dealing specifically with PostGIS and PostgreSQL 9.1.3 seg-faulting: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a great many different possible reasons for crashes. [Some of them have been fixed](http://www.pgadmin.org/development/changelog.php) in the [latest version 1.16.1](http://www.pgadmin.org/), release just last week.
You could try the new version and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 8):

1. Goto run and type %appdata% and go inside postgresql folder.
2. rename or delete pgadmin_histoqueries.xml file.
3. try opening the SQL query editor again.

Good luck!

Comment: For me it was a slithly different folder in %appdata%: `pgadmin`
After deleting whole folder pgadmin worked.
It seems that if you change the password of the postgres user, pgadmin 4 doesn't change saved password and crashes using the old one...

Answer (score 3):

PgAdmin crashes on me all of the time, but you eventually learn to be gentle with it.

Particularly, if it is waiting for a response from the PostgreSQL server, the window may freeze up until a reply is returned and parsed. When this happens, do *not* close the window, just wait.

Also, if you attempt to edit two different objects on the same parent, save one and click save on the other, this crashes the program.

My advice would be to only do one thing at a time, be patient, and don't be in a hurry to kill the process when it freezes up.

Comment: A good answer for PgAdmin freezes/crashes in general, but I neither did nor experienced anything you mentioned. I wouldn't mind PgAdmin being slow, I just hate that I can't write SQL code directly in it,  because it just breaks down. It's not up to me to kill it or not, it just commits suicide :-(

Answer (score 2):

Pgadmin3 was really unstable after installation on my ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It either freezes or crashes even while doing very basic things like looking data in a table or list tables in a schema etc.,  I almost gave up and started using the command line psql and luckily stumbled on [this blog](http://jamesseibel.com/blog/?p=31) which recommended to remove the pgadmin3 history file to solve the freezes and crashes. It worked for me.